# (Vue.js) How to use github page on 'Vue.js'

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages

I want to use github page on 'vue.js'

I tried to modify `/config/index.js` file.

```
build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
```

But i can't use github page.
[image]

Comment: Do you explicitly want to use the /docs folder option? Isn't the master option not working for you?

Comment: I want to use /docs folder option.

Comment: And do you have a docs folder in the root of the repo? Just tried replaying what you describe in your question and had no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: the "[Vue.js / Deployment /  Platform Guides GitHub Pages/](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#platform-guides) " documentation simply adds:

> If you are deploying to `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>/`, (i.e. your repository is at `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>`), set `publicPath` to "`/<REPO>/`".
>   For example, if your repo name is "`my-project`", your `vue.config.js` should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/my-project/'
    : '/'
}
```

[toast38coza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243806/toast38coza) illustrates that setup in his [blog post](https://blog.toast38coza.me/documenting-your-vuejs-project-with-github-pages/):

> ### Step 1: Setup the build system to build to `/docs`
>
> Edit: `config/index.js`
>
> ```
> find ../dist replace with ../docs
> change assetsPublicPath: '/', to: assetsPublicPath: './',
> ```
>
> Run:
>
> ```
> npm run build
> ```
>
> You should now have a docs folder in your project. Add and push to GitHub.

Check if those settings work better in your case.

Comment: I got the problem "npm run build".